# Implementing a throw ConcurrentModificationException in a HashSt code

Tags: java

In my hashset code
I want to implement a `ConcurrentModificationException` so that when anyone tries to add or remove after the iterator, it will thrown.

Here is part of the code:

```
          /** Need to add ConcurrentModificationException stuff*/
  public boolean hasNext()
  {
     if (current != null && current.next != null)
     {
        return true;
     }
     for (int b = bucketIndex + 1; b < buckets.length; b++)
     {
        if (buckets[b] != null)
        {
           return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
  }

   /** Need to add ConcurrentModificationException stuff*/
  public Object next()
  {
     if (current != null && current.next != null)
     {
        current = current.next; // Move to next element in bucket
     } else
     // Move to next bucket
     {
        do
        {
           bucketIndex++;
           if (bucketIndex == buckets.length)
           {
              throw new NoSuchElementException();
           }
           current = buckets[bucketIndex];
        } while (current == null);
     }
     return current.data;
  }
```

Comment: Have you looked into the next() method in `AbstractList$Itr`??

Answer (score 2):

Add an instance variable `int modcount = 0`; increment it every time a mutator (e.g. `add` or `remove`) is called.  When you create a new iterator, set its instance variable `int myModcount = modcount`; in its `next` method, if `myModtcount != modcount` then throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.  (I don't think that Java iterators throw this in the `hasNext` method, only in the `next` method.)

The rationale is that this lets you have multiple iterators, for example,

```
Iterator itr1 = hashMap.iterator();
hamMap.put(obj1, obj2);
Iterator itr2 = hashMap.iterator();
```

At this point `itr1.next()` will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`, but `itr2.next()` will not.

If your iterator implements `remove` or any other mutator, then these increment `myModcount` as well as `modcount`.

Comment: I tried as you said, but i'm still passing the first test case, but the last 2 cases aren't giving me the exception haha.

Comment: Ahhh I see. :O
I'll try to implement
as my tester has a try and catch block specifically for it.